# Remove condition of having minimum 15 reputation for upvotes

Tags: feature-request, voting

There are many times we have found a solution on stackexchange or stackoverflow sites those are useful and deserve an upvote but because of having less reputation those solutions didn't get that upvotes.
Please remove this condition else provide other alternatives to thanks, users.

Also If I have more than 15 reputations on other stackexchange or stackoverflow sites then also allow me to upvote their solutions.

Comment: Please give your votes anyhow! They will be counted as soon as you earned the priviledge.

Answer (score 14):

I applaud your desire to upvote those that have helped you. Sadly SPAM and other nefarious activities are a sad fact of the modern internet.  So these limits are in place.  But it turns out your idea [has been implemented](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus).  It is just that the thresholds are a bit higher than your proposal.

As soon as you have [200 points on any SE site](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/141648/what-is-the-association-bonus), then you will be given 100 points as an association bonus on all SE sites.  This is enough reputation to up-vote 40 times a day, on each site.   Not enough to downvote but that is only another 24 reputation away on each site.

So I would strongly encourage you to concentrate on one site, and go earn 200 reputation. You are already 1/3 of the way there on SO. This will then allow you upvote to your hearts content, network wide.

Comment: thanks for the information about 200 reputations, want to upvote your answer but sadly I need minimum 15 reputations :p